# клиент-серверная архитектура: контроль ошибок

Tags: javascript, архитектура, клиент-сервер

теоретический вопрос:

есть клиент-серверная архитектура (клиент-сайт и работа с БД-сервер), клиент посылает запросы на сервер и получает в ответ данные

такой вопрос - насколько клиент должен доверять корректности результатов, полученных от сервера? Должен ли клиент перед использованием проверять наличие полей, корректность значения в полях и т.д., т.е. что-то из серии

```
const res: string = from_server?.text || ''
```

с одной стороны если делать проверку на клиенте - это надёжно и гарантирует стабильную работу клиента при любых ситуациях, с другой стороны это двойная работа (ведь сервер тоже обрабатывает некорректные данные)

Comment: А какова конечная задача-то? Вот например вы сделали проверку, сервер прислал что попало, проверка завалилась - что дальше?

Comment: Если вы хотите, что бы клиентская часть не падала по ошибкам javaScript, то лучше проверяйте. Допустим ожидаете вы массив, а вам null пришел, а вы в коде попытаетесь применить forEach - и крах. Что делать, если пришло не то, что ожидалось, это уже второй вопрос. Ну и так же, надо понимать, что делает бэк - если вы сами, или ваша команда, то часть проверок можно убрать. Если это внешний сервис, по отношению к вам, то я бы проверял все критичное минимум.

Comment: @SwaD и этот "крах" ограничится лишь выплёвыванием ошибки в консоль, а пользователь зачастую сможет продолжить работу с клиентом (хотя какое-то время будет в недоумении из-за ошибки)

Comment: Чем более ПО устойчиво к ошибкам - тем оно лучше эксплуатируется. Если еще и проблему как-то читабельно будет выводить где-то - так вообще хорошо.

Comment: @andreymal Это если место ошибки обернуто в try catch или еще какой обработчик ошибки, иначе упадет целый кусок кода и все приложение "ляжет"

Comment: Кстати, в этом примере «что-то из серии» получится, что пользователь вместо строки увидит пустоту — действительно ли это лучше, чем условное `catch { alert('Ошибка, сорян') }`?

Comment: С сервера должны приходить данные в корректном формате. И с обговоренными статусами и данными.  Довольно странно проверять на null данные от сервера, если это не было обговорено заранее. Т.е. вот этот вот код `from_server?.text || ''` имеет место быть, если это было обговорено, что клиентская часть сама приобразует себе данные как ей надо (что и логично) хочет null в строку пустую преобразует, а хочет - в котиков

Comment: Важно понимать, что сервер никогда не доверяет клиенту и соответственно, делает всю работу по проверке, которую вы описали, в свою же очередь, клиент должен доверять серверу, т.к. это единственный источник данных. Если вы обработаете данные на клиенте (это делать можно и нужно, но немного в другом разрезе), и поймете, что там ошибка, то некий блок у вас все равно не заработает до правок на сервере, ибо как уже было сказано, это единственный источник данных (вы же не сможете сходить в другое место и забрать те же достоверные данные (не относится к ситуациям где присутствует некий fallback)).